# Why doesn’t Windows Vista get an address from the DHCP server?

Tags: networking, windows-vista, dhcp, ipv4

My Windows Vista PC does not get an IPv4 address from the DHCP server; viewing the network properties shows something (likely the DHCP request) being sent, but no packets being received. Manually entering an address, however, works fine and connects to the network. Also, if the Vista machine is replaced with a Windows XP or 7 or Linux one, the replacement does get an address automatically. What causes such problems? Is it a bug in Vista, or is there something wrong with my network card drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DHCP server or an intermediate device in the network path is buggy.

Starting with Windows Vista, DHCP requests [include the broadcast flag](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928233). Some network hardware do not recognise packets with this flag set¹. Fortunately, there is a registry entry which enables Windows Vista to fall back to packets without the flag if it does not receive a response.

In the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{your-network-card-GUID}` you need to set the DWORD entry `DhcpConnEnableBcastFlagToggle` to 1. If you’re unsure which subkey to use, you can enter it in all of them— it likely won’t cause any issues, since Windows 7 actually does this.

---

¹perhaps most notoriously the “Ubee” router-modems from Chello/UPC (an EU near-monopolist cable TV and internet operator) when put in “bridge mode”, which disables the router functions and permits you to connect directly to the internet and get a public IP.